# How can I prove $2\sup(S) = \sup (2S)$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

> Let $S$ be a nonempty bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $T = \{2s : s \in S \}$. Show $\sup T = 2\sup S$

*Proof*

Consider $2s  = s + s \leq \sup S + \sup S = 2\sup S $. $T \subset S$ where T is also bounded, so applying the lub property, we must have $\sup T \leq 2 \sup S$.

> On the other hand $2s + s - s \leq \sup T + \sup S - 3\sup S \implies 2\sup S \leq 2s + 2\sup S \leq \sup T $. Which gives the desired result.

Okay I am really worried about my other direction. Especially  $2\sup S \leq 2s + 2\sup S$, do I know that $2s$ is positive?

Also in the beginning, how do I know that $\sup S \leq 2 \sup S$? How do I know that the supremum is positive?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $T \subset S$. if $S=\{1\}$, then $T=\{2\}$, and the statement is not true.

Comment: Also, your claim that $-s \leq - 3\sup S$ is not true (I'm not sure where the 3 came from). For example, consider $S = \{-10, 1 \}$. Take $s= -10$, and $\sup S = 1 $.

Comment: To deal with negatives, just prove a similar statement for inf S and inf T assuming the elements are positive, then  mirror the argument.

Comment: All you really need to observe is that $M$ is an upper bound of $S$ iff $2M$ is an upper bound of $T$. The sup is the least upper bound.

Comment: @Zen, is that a different approach? Could you show me?

Comment: @sizz Remember to explicitly mention why sup$(T)$ exists in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't assume $s$ is positive, nor can you assume $\sup S$ is positive.
Your proof also assumes a couple of other weird things:

- $T \subset S$ is usually not true.
- $2s + s - s \le \sup T + \sup S - 3\sup S$ is not necessarily true.  Why would $-s \le -3\sup S$?

The first part of your proof is actually correct, ignoring the $T \subset S$ statement.
What you are saying is that any element of $T$, say the element $2s$, is bounded above by $2 \sup S$; thus $2 \sup S$ is an upper bound on $T$; thus $2 \sup S \ge \sup T$ by the least upper bound property.

For the second part of the proof, you need to show that $\sup T \ge 2 \sup S$.
To do this, you need to show that $\frac{\sup T}{2}$ is an upper bound on $S$.
This will imply $\frac{\sup T}{2} \ge \sup S$ by least upper bound property.

Comment: For the second part, is it just $s \in S \implies s = \frac{2s}{2}\leq \frac{ \sup T }{2}$. Again by lub property we have $\sup S \leq \frac{\sup T}{2}$

Comment: Hmm I got  +1 from an unknown user, does that mean I am correct?

Comment: @sizz Yes, I gave you +1 because that is correct.